# responsive 100% width banner with text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to add a text on my 100% width responsive banner

```css
.banner {
  display: flex;
}
.banner img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"> 
  <img src="images/truck.jpg" >
  <div>ala ma kota</div>
</div>
```

My banner is 2000x600 and I made it responsive but the text "ala ma kota" appears on the right I want to put it in center on the img

I've tried many metods with positions absolute and relative as well but effects are not satisfying. Do you have any idea?

Comment: please check below answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need text in center of image using `flex` please try this:

```css
.banner {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.banner img{
  width: 100%;
}
.text{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"> 
  <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/wnTN-QCFVqYVeCPaztGkCj7UpiY=/0x0:4243x3079/1200x800/filters:focal(1783x1201:2461x1879)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/65022936/TuSimple_Self_Drving_Truck_4_copy.0.jpg" >
  <div class="text">ala ma kota</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the combination of [`justify-content: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) on the parent `.banner`, in conjunction with [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) on the child `img`:

```css
.banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.banner img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; /* layering */
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100">
  <div>ala ma kota</div>
</div>
```

Note that `z-index: -1` is also added to the above snippet, though this is merely to show the text on top of the background.

Comment: Text is still is not in the center. please read question again !

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
.banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
.banner img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This...

```css
.banner {
  display: block;
  position:relative;
}
.banner img{
  width: 100%;
}
.text{
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:tranlateY(-50%);
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"> 
  <img src="images/truck.jpg" >
  <div class="text">ala ma kota</div>
</div>
```